# how to change textview's text in info window, from list of Strings

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2, infowindow

When my MapActivity opens, I request some info from my Firebase database that contains these data for certain hotel and after that it creates markers with loaded data.. I tried with snippet, but if my review is too long, it can not be shown..

```
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String name, double lat, double lon, String author, float foodRating,float serviceRating,float comfortRating,float averageRating, String review) {
        reviewList.add(review);

        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name)
                .position(position)
                .snippet("REVIEW: \n" + review + "\n").snippet(String.valueOf(averageRating)));
    }
```

so, I implemented InfoAdapter listener with it's method:

```
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.info_window, null, false);
        TextView reviewTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.review);
        reviewTextView.setText("");
        return view;
    }
```

and now I'd like to change text in reviewTextView whenever I click on different marker, to show each marker's (each hotel's) review...

I tried storing all reviews in onLoaded method into ArrayList called reviewList, but now I'm not sure how to pull out those reviews for a certain marker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Map` instead of an `ArrayList`, and put the reviews into the `Map` in the `onLoaded()` method using the `Marker`s' IDs as the keys. In the `getInfoWindow()` method, retrieve the review from the `Map` with the ID of the `Marker` passed in.

```
private Map<String, String> reviewMap = new HashMap<>();
...

@Override
public void onLoaded(String name, double lat, double lon, String author,
                     float foodRating, float serviceRating, float comfortRating,
                     float averageRating, String review) {

    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name)
                                  .position(position)
                                  .snippet("REVIEW: \n" + review + "\n")
                                  .snippet(String.valueOf(averageRating)));

    reviewMap.put(marker.getId(), review);
}
...

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.info_window, null, false);
    TextView reviewTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.review);
    String review = reviewMap.get(marker.getId());
    reviewTextView.setText(review);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Tnx Mike!  I just needed to change reviewMap to  Map<String, String> reviewMap = new HashMap<>();   because marker.getId();  is a String value

Comment: Oops, yeah, you're right. Guess I didn't look at the class summary close enough. Sorry 'bout that. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!